# Android phone connects to Airties only when phone or Airties is newly booted

Tags: wi-fi

I just got a new ISP, and they set me up with AirTies as a wireless AP for my network (the actual router is some beast that lives behind a networking panel in my condo).

Problem is whenever I get home from work my phone refuses to connect to the network. It doesn't give an error message anywhere I can see (are their connection logs somewhere?) it looks like it tries to connect once (briefly says "connecting..." and the signal indicator suddenly reduces momentarily, before it returns to the simple non-connected state and the signal indicator is full again), and then it just stops and even though the network is listed with a strong connection in the wifi list it doesn't try to connect to it further. I have tried "forgetting" the network and reconnecting and it still fails in the same fashion (although it does ask for a password).

The REALLY strange thing is if I restart my phone it connects to the network briefly (gets through "connecting...", "authentication", "obtaining ip address...", and some other process that happens too fast), but is disconnected within 5-10 seconds. If I restart the AirTies I can connect to it for a while at least (I haven't tested this for an extended session, but at least an hour or two).

My phone has no issue connecting to another network (E.g., the one I have at work, connects with no issues and without prompting), and none of my other devices (currently only one) have trouble connecting to the wifi.

Any thoughts on how I can further diagnose this issue?

Running a Nexus 5 (2013) with the latest available android OS for it (6.0.1) and security patches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I happened to read about a long standing issue where I would need to reset my phone entirely in order to fix a similar networking issue.. however it was such a pain to move all my Google 2fa tokens over. I decided if I was going to commit I will just take this opportunity to get a new phone entirely.

Since my new phone I have had no issues with the airties.

In summary: Factory reset your phone or get a new phone. I love Android to bits but this really needs to be looked into.